# Does the infinite iteration sequence of Newtons method always converge to a root?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Assume that a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ of Newton's method $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$ is convergent and set $x_\infty = \lim_{i\to\infty} x_i$. Furthermore assume that $f'(x_\infty) \neq 0$. How is it possible to show that $x_\infty$ is an solution to $f(x)=0$?

My solution for this were assuming that $x_{\infty+1}$=$x_\infty$ so
$$x_{\infty+1}=x_\infty-\frac{f(x_\infty)}{f'(x_\infty)}$$
$$0=-\frac{f(x_\infty)}{f'(x_\infty)}$$
$$0=-f(x_\infty)$$
$$f(x_\infty)=0$$

Comment: Newton's method only works for certain differentiable functions $f$ and when $x_0$ is a close enough "guess" of what $x_\infty$ might be. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: I'm taking Calculus Beta right now and this is an assignment problem. In the problem description it is derived from the tangent line equation that $x_i+1=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$. Furthermore the question is that we assume a sequence is convergent and $f'(x_\infty) \neq 0$ and for $x_\infty$ it is defined as $\lim_{i\to\infty} x_i $, how do we show that $x_\infty$ is an solution (the root) to $f(x)=0$. There aren't any other details about this sub-problem in the assignment.

Comment: One might be able to guess from your use of the term "Newton method" in your question that you mean $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i}{f'(x_i)}$. Yet, I would think you should put this info in your question, to make it clear. You dont need any $x_{\infty+1}$. If $x_i\to x_\infty$ then also $x_{i+1}\to x_\infty$, so $x_\infty=x_\infty-\frac{f(x_\infty)}{f'(x_\infty)}$. Welcome to MSE !

Comment: Incredible! Makes much more sense and thanks @Mirko!

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following proof works if we assume that $\{x_i\}_{i\geq 0}$ is a convergent sequence such that $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$ for all $i\geq 0$ (this assumption wasn't on your initial post, hence my comment) and $f$ and $f'$ are both continuous in some interval containing $x_\infty$ (i.e. $f$ is continuously differentiable in $x_\infty$).

Your intuition that "$x_{\infty}=x_{\infty+1}$" is good, but doesn't yet constitute a proof. We can use the fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{i\to\infty} x_i=\lim_{i\to\infty} x_{i+1}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736773/why-do-x-n-and-x-n1-tend-towards-the-same-limit); this stems from the fact that $\{x_{i+1}\}_{i\geq 0}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_i\}_{i\geq 0}$) to deduce the following:
$$\lim_{i\to \infty} x_{i+1}=\lim_{i\to \infty}\left(x_i-\frac{f(x_{i})}{f'(x_i)}\right) ~~\implies~~x_{\infty}=x_{\infty}-\frac{f(x_{\infty})}{f'(x_{\infty})},$$
by sum and fraction of limits and [the convergence of $\{f(x_i)\}_{i\geq 0}$ and $\{f'(x_i)\}_{i\geq 0}$ if $f,f'$ are continuous](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Image_of_Sequence/Real_Number_Line) and $f'(x_{\infty})\neq 0$. Substracting $x_{\infty}$ on both sides and multiplying by $-f'(x_{\infty})$, we obtain:
$$-\frac{f(x_{\infty})}{f'(x_{\infty})}=0 ~~~~\text{and thus}~~~~ f(x_{\infty})=0.$$
That is, $x_{\infty}$ is a solution for $x$ in $f(x)=0$.

---

I'd like to remark (as in my comment) that the Newton-Rhapson method does **not** always converge to a root; this proof required fairly strong assumptions. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407659/why-does-the-newton-raphson-method-not-converge-for-some-functions?rq=1)'s an interesting discussion about this.